# Error Encountered While Converting Python Script to Executable (.exe) Using PyInstalle

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I attempted to convert my script into an executable file (*.exe), but encountered an error during the file creation process. The error traceback is as follows:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_ctypes.py", line 53, in __init__
    File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 376, in __init__
    OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 58, in load
    File "pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 50, in load_objects
    File "pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 454, in LoadLibrary
    File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_ctypes.py", line 55, in __init__
    pyimod03_ctypes.install.<locals>.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 
   'C:\\Users\\ahmedb\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI315562\\libiconv.dll'. Most likely this 
   dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.

   During the handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_ctypes.py", line 53, in __init__
   File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 376, in __init__
   OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

   The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "New_project.py", line 16, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
    File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
    File "pyzbar\pyzbar.py", line 7, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
    File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
    File "pyzbar\wrapper.py", line 151, in <module>
    File "pyzbar\wrapper.py", line 148, in zbar_function
    File "pyzbar\wrapper.py", line 127, in load_libzbar
    File "pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 60, in load
    File "pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 50, in load_objects
    File "pyzbar\zbar_library.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 454, in LoadLibrary
    File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_ctypes.py", line 55, in __init__
    pyimod03_ctypes.install.<locals>.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 
    C:\\Users\\ahmedb\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI315562\\libiconv.dll'. Most likely this 
    dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
```

The command I used to create my application was:

```
`pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --icon 
"C:/Users/ahmedb/Desktop/app/logo.ico" --add-data 
"C:/Users/ahmedb/Desktop/app/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml;." --add-binary 
"C:/Users/ahmedb/Desktop/app/libiconv.dll;." 
"C:/Users/ahmedb/Desktop/app/New_project.py`"
```

I have attempted various methods, but unfortunately, none have been successful in resolving this issue

Comment: Check the file path for `"C:/Users/ahmedb/Desktop/app/libiconv.dll;." ` also not sure about the `;.` at the end of the `dll` and `xml` paths as well as about ` at the end of the `py` file

Comment: The file is there

Comment: rning: The numpy.array_api submodule is still experimental. See NEP 47.
  __import__(package)
0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.